# Obtaining a bucket retention period with golang and InfluxDB

Tags: go, influxdb, flux, retention

fellow programmers,

I have a use case where I run a influxDB instance in another container (and possibly host) for the purpose of collecting some data. I would want to obtain the retention period of the InfluxDB bucket before writing to it, so that I omit errors, which occur if it is violated. However, I do not seem to find an option to do that using the InfluxDB Golang client.

Any idea on how that could be achieved. I also looked in the Flux language specification, but nothing seems to serve my use case as well.

I tried looking into the Flux documentation and the Golang Influx Client API.